# Why does Ubuntu claim to uptodate when there was no update for month?

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

I have an Ubuntu LTS 16.04.02 with an 4.4.x Kernel from March. 
When I try to update the system it claims to be uptodate. This is not true. So why do not get the updates?

```
root@p1sr1:~# uname -a
Linux p1sr1 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:27:09 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

root@p1sr1:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial


root@p1sr1:~# sudo apt-get update
OK:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
OK:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
OK:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig                 

root@p1sr1:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.**
```

**Edit:**
after some further information via the comments, it seems that the source.list seems to be not ok on my system. 
Does anyone have a default sourcelist for LTS 16.04.2, I like to compare with my system.

**Edit II**
After getting the correct source.lists I could now update to Kernel 4.10 but I am still on LTS 16.04.2 !! 
I tried to do an dist-upgrade but this comes back with 0 packages to update... So I am in a much better state now but the initial question: 
How can I upgrade from LTS 16.04.2 to LTS 16.04.3 is still on my desk. Any hint is highly well come!

Comment: Your `apt-get update` list is pretty short. Have you altered your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?

Comment: also the newest release is 17.04. You may be uptodate for xenial but not have all the newest packages because they haven't been backported to 16.04.

Comment: I would like to update to LTS 16.04.3 --
and I am not aware of updates to the sources.list --
does any one may have a default sources.list so that I can compare this to  mine?

Comment: Can you show your output of `grep -r --include='*.list' '^\s*deb' /etc/apt/sources.list*`? For restoring defaults if you want that, see https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/367990

Comment: HWE are not automatically installed. So you will not automatically be updated to 16.04.03. (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: oot@p1sr1:~# grep -r --include='*.list' '^\s*deb'  /etc/apt/sources.list*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/x2go-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial main

Comment: @Bruni the hwe Packages are not found, the page you linked does not mention that a further ppa is needed. So I like to confirm if the absense is correct and if so where to get the packages from?

Comment: @MBushveld Indeed a further ppa should not be needed, so you need to check your sources.  However,  it would be better to edit your question than to comment.

Comment: @MBushveld you're missing the `xenial-{security,updates}` repositories.

Comment: @MBushveld If you want to upgrade to 16.04.3, I think you need to do a `dist-upgrade` and not just an `upgrade`.  `upgrade` may be a bit  conservative.  As the documentation for this command says, "New versions of currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the install status of another package will be left at their current version."  This comment is in addition to your missing repositories -- you need to fix that, too.

Comment: @Ray Neither the `upgrade` nor the `dist-upgrade` action is needed to install and use an officially backported kernel (though `sudo apt update` or similar will have to be run after fixing `sources.list` and before installing the new packages). HWE kernels are provided by differently named packages,  which are installed with the `install` action rather than upgraded to. As  Bruni says, to enable a HWE kernel on 16.04, see [LTS Enablement Stacks → Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Xenial Xerus](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus).

Comment: @Ray I did successful enable HWE Kernel, but I am still on LTS 16.04.2 there is no error message at all. Reading the above comments I should get the 16.04.3 out of the box -- but I dont... How to track down what stopp the update??

Comment: @MBushveld I'm not so sure I'm saying the same thing as Eliah.  I know I can't be since I don't know what "HWE Kernel" means.  You're talking about going up from 16.04.2 to 16.04.3?  I only suggested `dist-upgrade` since I was wondering if conflict is preventing the packages from going up a version.  If you're frustrated, you can try installing `aptitude`.  I actually use that instead of `apt-get`.  Then do a `sudo aptitude update; sudo aptitude full-upgrade`.  See if that works?  (There shouldn't be a difference, actually.)

Comment: @MBushveld Also, instead of playing around with `sources.list`, you can try the graphical interface that's described here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu to get a "new" sources.list.